# Objects of a class that does not have operator ==() are converted to another type

Tags: c++, c++17

Why objects of class A are converted to bool (or to int) in the following code:

```
class A
{
public:

    operator bool() const { return true; }
    operator int() const { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    return A() == A();
}
```

and it is not clear what are they converted to? to bool or to int?

Comment: You could always add a `cout` statement to find out which one is being called.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot where to add 'explicit'?

Comment: Just before the `operator` keyword

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot did you try this?

Comment: [yes](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_gPSA6). Now it fails correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to find what to do with `==`. That's going to involve looking for member, non-member, and built-in candidates for `==`. In this case, we don't have any member/non-member candidates, so that part is easy.

The built-in candidates are, from [[over.built]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#13) (emphasis mine, and abridged):

> For every pair of **promoted arithmetic types** *L* and *R*, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> `bool    operator==(L, R);`

The [promoted arithmetic types](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#2.sentence-2) are the integral types after promotion and the floating point types. Any integral type smaller than `int` (including `bool`) [promotes](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#prom-1) to `int`. (`float` [promotes](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#fpprom-1) to `double`, but `float` is still a "promoted arithmetic type"). The important part of this for us really is that the "promoted arithmetic types" include `int`, but not `bool`. So effectively, we have built-in candidates like:

```
bool operator==(int, int);
bool operator==(int, long);
bool operator==(long, int);
bool operator==(long, long);
bool operator==(int, float);
// etc.
```

There are a *lot* of candidates in this set. But we can basically divide them into two groups.

The first group consists entirely of:

```
bool operator==(int, int);
```

This candidate is viable, we have a clear best conversion sequence since going through `operator int() const` is better than going through `operator bool() const` and then promoting.

The second group consists of every other candidate. For every promoted arithmetic type that is not `int`, we have two equivalent conversion sequences: one through the `bool` conversion and one through the `int` conversion. Neither is better than the other. When I first wrote this answer, I thought that this meant these candidates would be rejected - but that is surprisingly not the case, as T.C. points out: an ambiguous conversion sequence is [treated equivalently to](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#10.sentence-2) any other user-defined conversion sequence.

So from the first group, we have one viable candidate which involves a user-defined conversion sequence. And from the second group, we have a lot of candidates with ambiguous conversion sequences - which importantly are considered equivalently good to the `operator==(int, int)` candidate from the first group.

As a result, `A() == A()` is ill-formed. There is no best viable candidate. gcc is wrong to accept this.

---

Note that gcc does reject very similar other presentations of this same idea:

```
void check(int, int);
void check(float, float);

check(A(), A()); // gcc and clang reject, msvc accepts
```

Comment: Having an ambiguous conversion sequence doesn't make the candidate non-viablel; it just makes the call ill-formed if the candidate is selected. Since [such a sequence is considered indistinguishable from every other user-defined conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#10.sentence-2), the call is indeed ambiguous according to the standard. The issue here is that [over.built]'s list of candidates is way too broad.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. This may or may not be the intended behavior, but is what the current wording prescribes.

Comment: @T.C. This seems... wrong. But I don't want to touch [over] with a 5 foot pole.

Comment: @T.C. SO needs a multi-author concept.